# Instantsearch.js/Hits widget: transforming data on refinement

Tags: javascript, algolia

I'm using Instantsearch.js with the `refinementList` and `hits` widgets.

I have a faceted search/`refinementList` of `colors`.

- Each item has an array of `images`.
- Each `image` has a `url`, and an array of `colors`
- When you filter by **Red**, e.g., I want to show the `image` that has a **Red** in its `colors` array.

So it seemed logical to just adjust the data sent to my `item` template on any filter of the `refinementList`.

It seemed at first I could use `widget.hits`'s `transformData` callback: https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#hits, however, it seems `transformData` is not necessarily called when filtering the `refinementList`. If a result is showing, and still showing after a refinementList filter, transformData doesn't seem to be called.

Any advice on methods to achieve this, or any alternate approaches?

Here's where I'm currently at: https://jsfiddle.net/timkelty/LyuL5eze/7/

**How its supposed to work:**

- Test Product Config - default image (no filters): **Admiral Ackbar 128Px**
- click brown
- click pink
- Test Product Config's image is now **Poochie**
- Uncheck pink, check blue
- Test Product Config's image is now **Bowie**

Great - except this *only* works if the `item` is re-rendered from the previous state.

**E.g., with no filters checked (doesn't work, this is the problem):**

- Test Product Config - default image (no filters): **Admiral Ackbar 128Px**
- Check pink
- Image should be **Poochie**, but is still **Admiral Ackbar 128Px**, presumably because `transformData` hasn't been called on the item, because it already existed and didnt need to be be re-rendered.

Comment: Hi Tim, the best way to help you on this question would be to get any live jsFiddle or demo demonstrating your current issue. Can you do that?

Comment: @vvo just updated my original post with more details and a jsfiddle.

Comment: Ok that's clearly a bug, can new open it on github: https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch.js/issues

That's some amazing debugging session you have done here. Thanks